# Session Handler behaves like object

Tags: php, session, object, warnings

I want to force $_SESSION behave like object using custom session handler. Code as follows,

```
$_SESSION = [
'user' => [
    'id' => '7',
    'name' => 'James',
    'lastname' => 'Bond',
    'login' => '007',
    'pass' => 'qwe7fyqw9mhev8qhr',
],
'kill' => [
    'Mr_Muscle' => [
        'status' => 'alive',
    ],
    'Joe_Black' => [
        'status' => 'dead',
    ]
],
];

$session = new Session();

echo $session->user->name;

$session->kill->Mr_muscle->status = 'dead';

$session->save();
```

I did it almost but I get warning:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/project/mvc/bootstrap.php on line 80

when I'm trying to create new value, in this case:

```
$session->kill->Dr_Quinn->status = 'dead';
```

Value will be created but I don't want to hide this warning, I want to do away with it.

```
class Session
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $this->arrayToObject($value);
    }

    private function arrayToObject($array) {
        if (!is_array($array)) {
            return $array;
        }

        $object = new stdClass();
        if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
            foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
                $name = strtolower(trim($name));
                if (!empty($name)) {
                    $object->$name = $this->arrayToObject($value);
                }
            }
            return $object;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $_SESSION = json_decode(json_encode(get_object_vars($this)), true);
    }
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
if (!isset($session->kill->Mr_muscle)) 
    $session->kill->Mr_muscle = new stdClass();
$session->kill->Mr_muscle->status = 'dead';
```

to avoid this warning.

Comment: thanks, we're little closer to the solution  but how to do it "on the fly"? Sometime I'll want to run `$session->car->Fiat_500->status = 'crashed';` and this is totally "new" path

Comment: Then you would have to create two new objects, to avoid this warning. PHP is silently creating the objects by itself, but with this warning. So you could just do: `$session->car = new stdClass(); $session->car->Fiat = new stdClass(); $session->car->Fiat->status = "crashed";`

Comment: I figure out that i need have to nest `__set($name, $value)
    { $this->$name = $this->arrayToObject($value);}` and ` __get($name) { if (!isset($this->{$name})) { $this->{$name} = new stdClass(); } return $this->{$name};  }` to each stdClass().

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind is that for example your `'Mr_Muscle'` becomes lowercase in the constructor, so `mr_muscle`